# Access callback Drupal не возвращает true

Tags: php, drupal

Ребят такая проблема имеется страничка на которую могут зайти только те пользователи которые есть в отдельной таблице. соотвественно код:
hook_menu
Код PHP

```
function niiar5c_menu()
{
    // Blank5c
        $items['blank5c/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'Бланк 5С',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('module_blankadd'),
        'file' => 'modul.pages.inc',
        'access callback' => 'module_access',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => 2,
  );

    return $items;
}
```

Код функции которая после проверки должка вернуть access callback true в которойи происходит проверка айди пользователь со списком. Отдельно код работает.

Код PHP

```
function module_access () {

  global $user;
  $uuid = $user->uid;

  $nids = db_select('whoboss', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('name'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();

if (in_array($uuid, $nids)){
return TRUE;} else return FALSE;

}
```

Страница тупо выводит You are not authorized to access this page. Помогите разобраться с access callback

Comment: А если в `module_access` добавить отладочный вывод и вывести `$uuid`, `$nids` и результат  выполнения? Может у того пользователя нет прав. И зачем такая странная конструкция `if () return true else return false`? Можно же проще: `return in_array($uuid, $nids)`

Comment: На отдельной странице я выводил результат работы и было все нормально. Сама функция работает и возвращает true и false. проблема в том что если я хочу вернуть true для 'access callback' то ничего не происходит. Если в access callback поставить значение true вместо функции 'module_access' то доступ откроется всем. Поэтому я и провожу проверку через отдельную функцию.

Comment: т.е. если в `module_access` вместо всего кода написать просто `return true`, то ничего не работает? В этом проблема?

Comment: Именно)) Я уже очень долго мучаюсь с этим вопросом и не могу понять как же заставить все это работать.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110607/access-callback-function-does-not-return-false-and-true-value

See my answer in english: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32132782/1041470